# Unknown column 'tr' in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1054

I have this MySQL query, which is failing every time:

`update exp_companies set company = 'Some Intermodal Container Company', auth_user = 'Some User', c_code = 'SICC', contact = 'Somes Boss', ph = '012-555-1234' where uid = 3`

The error I get is:

```
mySQL Error 1054: Unknown column 'tr' in 'where clause'
```

I have never encountered this before. I have expressed this query many ways, omitting parts, etc. But nowhere in the query there is column 'tr', mentioned in error, yet it fails.

```
if($opi == "exp_commit") {

   $dbi = sql_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass, $mydb);

   $query = "select * from wmd_companies where uid = $new_scac";

   $result = sql_query($query, $dbi);

    if(!$result) { mydb_error($dbi, $query); }
      $scac_row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
      $scac_company = $scac_row[1];  
      $scac_code = $scac_row[2];   
      $scac_contact = $scac_row[3];
      $scac_ph = $scac_row[4];
      $scac_email = $scac_row[5];

      $exp_query = "update exp_companies set company = '$scac_company', auth_user = '$dr_name', c_code = '$scac_code', contact = '$scac_contact', ph = '$scac_ph', company_email = '$scac_email' where uid = $exp_id"; 

   $result = sql_query($exp_query, $dbi);


  if (!$result) { mydb_error($dbi, $exp_query); }
     echo "Success! <meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"2;      URL=admin.php?opi=admin&what=list\"> $b";

  }
```

Comment: So you hardcode all your queries? or are you hiding the fact that your not using prepared or escaped queries, and its simply a SQL injection problem?

Comment: Is this the complete sql query or something more is missing in question? What is the error when you try to execute via sql editors/developer tools?

Comment: here is the complete (novice level) code block ... I might add several other similary blocks parse correctly:

Comment: No my queries are not hard code. I just showed the error reported the query is:   "update exp_companies set company = '$scac_company', auth_user = '$dr_name', c_code = '$scac_code', contact = '$scac_contact', ph = '$scac_ph', company_email = '$scac_email' 
   where uid = $exp_id";

Comment: add column one by one in update query with where clause.. so that you sure what the issue is coming from. Is that coming from query or column issue..

Comment: I tried stripping the update query down to one update at a time and each result returns the same unknown column 'tr' but as you see from the query the column 'tr' is never referenced. I have even tried closing all mysql_connections and using new connections. I have checked the resource id's of both sql_connect and sql_query.  I do not understand where this column 'tr' is coming from

Comment: Still unsure how the query threw an unknown column 'tr' error but when I changed the query to where auth_user = '$old_name' there error disappeared ... must have had something to do with using the uid reference.  thanks for the consideration(s)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

use '$new_scac' use the string to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read How to Answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer